# Can abstracted CountDownTimer class modify layout view objects linked to an activity?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I am a computer hobbyist who is working on a simple trivia game. In order to increase the difficulty of the game, I'm adding a countdown timer.

Initially, I defined a new countdown timer within my GameActivity file, overriding the onTick code so it would swap in new ImageView content with each tick. This worked just fine as long as the player waited for the timer to finish. However, if the player guessed an answer before the timer finishes, the .cancel() method caused the entire app to crash.

In an attempt to solve this problem, I created a new class (GameTimer.java) that extends the CountDownTimer class. I then call an instance of this class from the appropriate locations within my GameActivity file. Everything works swimmingly when my timer's ontick method is simply counting down time with System.out.println. But, when I try to to access the ImageView on the layout, I can see that findViewById() is not defined for this class (code is appended).

Once a layout is inflated by a certain activity, is it possible for an external class to access/change items on that layout? I understand that findViewById is a method of the android.app.Activity class, and my countdown timer is only extending Java Object.

I'm appending the code for my countdown timer, but I suspect it is not much help. I hope my question is abstract enough that I don't need to post my gameActivity code. If that code will help, I'll try to clean it up a bit before posting it here.

```
package edu.trinity.madvertising;

import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class TrinityGameTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    private ImageView myTimerVisual;

    public TrinityGameTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        System.out.println("Timer has been started.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        System.out.println("Timer has been stopped.");

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long arg0) {

        // The problem is here. I cannot findViewById

        ImageView myTimerVisual = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview_game_timer);

        myTimerVisual.setImageResource(R.drawable.timerbar5);
        System.out.println("Tick. Tick.");


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have noticed, `findViewById` cannot be used outside an Activity. You should pass `GameActivity's` Context in the constructor of `TrinityGameTimer`

```
GameActivity mContext;

public TrinityGameTimer(GameActivity context,long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    mContext = context
    System.out.println("Timer has been started.");
}
```

In your `onTick` method:

```
mContext.myTimerVisual.setImageResource(R.drawable.timerbar5);
```

You don't need to `findViewById` in this case, or keep a reference of `ImageView`(or any other widget).

Comment: Thank you Vikram. This solves my problem and I now have a better understanding of how to access context.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it is possible for external class to access Activity layout, you just need to pass a reference to your Activity in your Timer and then use `activity.findViewById(..)`.